# Find the convolution of two functions-an exponential function and a Heaviside function

Tags: convolution

[My math problem. I know that g(t)=5u(t)-5u(t-4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNTTP.png)

Comment: I'm having difficulty finding the convolution using the Heaviside function. If anyone can help me with it, that would be great.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: That $e^{3t}$ is not "normal"! Normal would be $ce^{3t^2}$.

Comment: Hint: In general $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) u(t-a)\,dt=\int_a^\infty f(t)\,dt$.

Comment: Can you please show your own attempt? As it is it's not incredibly easy to give advice outside of "use the definition of the convolution" without just solving the problem for you

Comment: Try writing out the integral explicitly and see where you can go from there.